# Object.assign but throw error if names clash

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is there a way to use Object.assign so that it throws an error if there are clashing top level properties? Or must we manually write our functionality to do so?

Comment: add some code to illustrate your question

Comment: A big reason to use `Object.assign` is to *override* existing properties in place of new ones for immutability...

Comment: can we use proxy objects?

Comment: yeah sure, Proxy objects are ok with me

Comment: @AlexanderMills i posted an answer try it .it may help you.

Comment: thanks, I have posted a "great" question it may help you to upvote :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there a way to use Object.assign so that it throws an error if there are clashing top level properties?

No.  What you've asked for is not a feature of `Object.assign()`.

> Or must we manually write our functionality to do so?

Yes, you must write your own or find something someone else has already written.  Here's a different function that will throw if any top-level source properties match a property already on the target.  Since this is not the behavior of `Object.assign()`, it seems appropriate that this is a new function with a different name:

```
function mergeObjects(target, ...sources) {
    let originalProperties = new Set(Object.keys(target));
    // preflight for any top-level property name conflicts so we can throw before copying anything
    for (let src of sources) {
        for (let prop of Object.keys(src)) {
            if (originalProperties.has(prop)) {
                throw new Error(`target already has property ${prop}`);
            }
        }
    }
    return Object.assign(target, ...sources);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let a = {1: '1', 2: '2', 3: '3'}

const pDummy = new Proxy(a, {
  set: function(target, prop, value, receiver) {
    if(target[prop] === undefined){
      target[prop] = value;
      // Reflect.set(target, prop, value);
      return true
    }
    else {
      throw new Error(`Already assigned property ${prop} `);
      // return false;
    }
  }
})

const test = Object.assign(pDummy, {4:'4', 5: '5'});
console.log('test', test);
const test1 = Object.assign(pDummy, {1:'4', 8: '5'});
console.log('test1', test1);
```

Comment: nice thinking, I will see if it works, not sure if it will?